# Handling java List in dwr addRows function

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dwr

I am calling ajaxcontroller to get data from server. 
ajaxController.fetchCounts(callFetchcounts);

callFetchcounts, this function will be called once i got the data.
I am handling it like this:

```
var callFetchcounts = function(data) {
if( data.length > 0){
    dwr.util.addRows("rounded-corner",[data] , cellFuncs, { escapeHtml:false });
}}

var cellFuncs = [
 function(data) {return data.category},
 function(data) {return data.count},
 function(data) {return "<a href=''>Edit</a>"}
];
```

From the ajaxController i will get List of objects. (I can even get array of objects.)
I want to populate a table where number of rows = number of elements in the result List/array. Number of columns = number of elements in each list object.
I want to populate columns with List object's data.

How to do this? I am struck here.
Can any one please help me with an example.

Thanks,
Tiru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help - http://www.packtpub.com/article/dwr-java-ajax-user-interface-basic-elements-part2 :)

Answer (score 0):

You almost  accomplished you mission!
All you need to do is adjust few points on your code, check it out:

```js
function fillTable(data) {
  if( data.length > 0){
   var cellFuncs = [
    function(data) {return data.category},
    function(data) {return data.count},
    function(data) {return "<a href='#'>Edit</a>"}
   ];
   
   // You don't have to use [data] if data is a list(array) of objects
   // User [data] only if data is a single object
   dwr.util.addRows("rounded-corner", data , cellFuncs, { escapeHtml:false });
  }
}
```